# Getting STANDARD Html from Outlook mailbody

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-addin

I am working on a Outlook AddIn where I have to get the Outlook mailbody and store it in a control which can be manipulated for my requirement.
The code is like this:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Explorer oExplorer = oApp.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.Selection oSelection = oExplorer.Selection;
foreach (object item in oSelection)
{
htmlEditor1.Html = mailItem.HTMLBody;
}
```

I checked for htmlbody format using

```
oldMailItem.BodyFormat.ToString();
```

It is giving olFormatHTML which is different from standard HTML.

How I can get the standard HTML from Outlook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML produced by Outlook is valid XHTML markup and will display in a browser. It contains a bunch of additional Microsoft-specific tags, but these are ignored by browsers and the message will (for the most part) degrade gracefully.

If you really want to remove this extra markup and be left with just standard HTML, you could use a parser such as the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to strip out any tags that have a namespace prefix (e.g. `<o:p>`). From what i've seen, Outlook uses `o:`, `w:`, `v:` and `m:` to denote its mail, text, shape and math markup respectively.

As i've said, however, it is probably not necessary to remove these tags as they do not prevent the message from being displayed in a `WebBrowser` control or similar.

Comment: Smith, thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely try agility pack. Yes, what u have told is true: we can use webbrowser control to display the content, but I am using a third party Rich text Editor control which have the capability to edit the content (colored,bol,italic,size...). Although it is a Rich Text editor, in this case it is only supporting plain text of outlook body and not fully functioning in case of rich text.